# Which processor family should I choose when compiling the kernel for an Intel i3/i5/i7 family CPU?

Tags: kernel

I have Intel® Core™ i5-2310 CPU @ 2.90GHz × 4. Which processor family should I to use when configuring kernel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If the kernel is for use on *this processor only*, you can choose `Core 2/newer Xeon`
- For the widest compatibility (portability), it's best to stick to the default `Pentium Pro` (i386) or `Generic x86_64` (amd64) architectures.

Comment: Will I have 100% compatibility with my processor if I choose "Core 2"?

Comment: Yes, absolutely 110% (notice it's the latest Intel option available)  :)